# How to get latency metric from AWS CloudWatch Application ELB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, monitoring, amazon-cloudwatch

Is there any way to get latency from AWS/ApplicationELB namespace? I know it is available in the AWS/ELB namespace, but I need it for AWS/ApplicationELB, as this is what I use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The latency metric on ELB is comparable to the `TargetResponseTime` metric on ALB.

**ELB Latency definition:** ([source](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-cloudwatch-metrics.html))

> The total time elapsed, in seconds, from the time the load balancer
>   sent the request to a registered instance until the instance started
>   to send the response headers.

**ALB TargetResponseTime definition:** ([source](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-cloudwatch-metrics.html#load-balancer-metrics-alb))

> The time elapsed, in seconds, after the request leaves the load
>   balancer until a response from the target is received. This is
>   equivalent to the target_processing_time field in the access logs.

### Further Reading

- [AWS Documentation - CloudWatch Metrics for Your Application Load Balancer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-cloudwatch-metrics.html)

Comment: "after the request leaves the load balancer" - What does it mean? After the request opens a connection to instance or after the request is fully sent to instance? I have a service, which accepts connection, but doesn't read from socket, until needed. I try to understand now, what number TargetResponseTime will show. The same question is about "until a response from the target is received." Fully received?